# rendering open graph meta tags in wordpress

Tags: post-meta, open-graph

I am trying to find some information about how to render/display Open Graph Meta Tags on my Wordpress page.

What i found there is a lot of data how to set up this for social media, ADD Open graph meta tags, but nothing how to read and display in Wordpress.

What i want to do is to render/display news/article and display in the same way as twitter card but on my Wordpress page.

example. i have link - http://www.bbc.com/news/av/world-us-canada-42589965/explosion-as-two-planes-collide-in-toronto-pearson

WP reads link meta and display it similar way as on twitter https://twitter.com/BBCWorld/status/949624397182234625

Any idea how to do this? I hope that there is a way to do this in PHP and WP.

Thank you for help and resources.

Best

Comment: The [Open Graph Protocol website](http://ogp.me/) links to this [PHP library](https://github.com/scottmac/opengraph) for consuming Open Graph data.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress core supports [embeds](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds) from a variety of sites, including Twitter.

Embedding content is as simple as pasting the URL of the tweet (or whatever) into it's own paragraph in the content editor. The embed will be displayed much like the examples you've provided.

Comment: hi, thanks. it does not work this way. embeded is only for certain websites.What i need is generic web, like bbc, blogs etc with og. meta tags. best